# Sci-fi film or TV-show including aliens, worm forced into feet or mouth

Tags: story-identification

I only have vague memories about this but it's an American or maybe British sci-fi film or TV-show set in our past, present time or in a near future judging by the environments, that includes aliens that forces a worm to enter restrained humans' heels or mouth from glass vials.
A terrified victim strapped to a chair in a surgical room of sorts at one point had his mouth forced open with a steel ring so that the worm could enter. If I recall correctly there were also floating metal orbs in the sky and a horse-carriage driver wearing a very oddly shaped mask. Hope I'm not mixing up things here but this is all I remember and I haven't found anything about it. It's not body snatchers. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like a mash-up of Stargate SG-1 and Doctor Who

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: The worms in the mouth made me thing of the TV show Dark Skies from the late 1990s. Dont know about the horse carriage driver though... you can watch it here, see if it rings any bells... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vA49U87Va0s&list=PLQpUOh89EH0y5Jtv2_91rKrkTS_gLJb1Y

Comment: I watched it as a young kid around the mid-90's and I think it could of been made during that decade. Speaking of Dr Who it did feel British considering how the environments and props looked. Sorry it was so long ago I don't remember much.

Comment: @Bastron They weren't making Doctor Who in the 1990's, if it was british there is a very long shot that it could be Invasion Earth. Not much of what you describe matches though. you can watch it on Youtube here... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsH7X_OpKrc&list=PLzjVl31ynMrDJkd6JOMuuKLmV8LyPOdbU

Comment: It's not dark skies but thanks anyway!

Comment: I know Dr Who was way earlier I meant it reminded me of that series. No not invasion earth either but thanks!

Comment: It's a pilot for a failed TV series called White Dwarf! Stay tuned for a full answer

Comment: That name rings a bell!! I'll patiently await more information or clips if you have any :) as I haven't been able to find more info about White Dwarf. Thanks in advance Vanguard!

Comment: @Bastron It's pretty obscure now. I remember being fascinated by it as a kid when it aired, and for years I thought I might have imagined it (the visuals of the floating orbs you mentioned really stuck with me) until I finally remembered the name a few years ago and was able to watch it again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**This is [White Dwarf](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114926/) (1995).**

[image]

Originally a TV pilot that flopped after (I recall) significant hype, it stands alone as a TV movie.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Dwarf_(film)):

> In the year 3040, New York medical student Driscoll Rampart (Neal McDonough) is completing his internship on Rusta, a rural planet which due to it being tidally locked to its primary, is divided into contrasting halves of day and night with the halves separated by a wall. The two sides are involved in a civil war: The day side containing a Victorian-styled colony is at odds with the night containing a medieval kingdom. The differences between the two cultures leaves Rampart in a state of wonder. Rampart arrives from Earth for a six-month stint at the Light Side clinic run by Dr. Akada (Paul Winfield). Rampart's ambition is to eventually set up a private practice in Manhattan on Park Avenue.

**...set in our past, present time or in a near future judging by the environments...**

The film had a bizarre mix of sci-fi, medieval fantasy, and pastoral frontier aesthetics, which is possibly why it failed to impress, and is probably why you're having a difficult time remembering the era in which it was set.

**...aliens that forces a worm to enter restrained humans' heels or mouth from glass vials....**

(Trigger warning for the very squeamish.)

> [image]

There is a worm-like parasite that is used at one point to assassinate a sleeping man. The parasite is in a glass bottle held against the man's heel.

**If I recall correctly there were also floating metal orbs in the sky...**

[image]

The planet, having a distinct day side and night side, is kept habitable by "Regulators" - floating steel orbs of ancient alien origin. They don't rally factor into the film's story much aside from explaining how a tidally locked planet could be habitable, but they feature in a lot of establishing shots.

**...and a horse-carriage driver wearing a very oddly shaped mask.**

[image]

The carriage that brings Rampart from his (unseen) landing site to the day side colony is an old horse & buggy, but the coachman is wearing a strange gas mask.

[Here](https://www.chicagotribune.com/news/ct-xpm-1995-05-21-9506130368-story.html) is an article with a bit more detail about the show's plot, setting, and production. The film is pretty obscure now, but I was able to watch it online a year or so ago (even if I remembered the link I doubt I'd be able to add it here) and while it's a bit clunky at times, it's a lot of fun.

Comment: That's it!! You solved it Vanguard :D thank you so much! Any idea where to watch clips of it? I couldn't find anything on YouTube or anywhere else.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Google isn't giving me much, and I can't recall where I was able to stream it a few years back. I couldn't even find many good screenshots for this answer. But I'll keep an eye out for it for you, because I recommend watching it. It's weird, but totally unique.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7KA5XrI4wE although it's blocked in my country

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxOg_-cGOuw same here

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mt90AYy8mvc yet another one

Comment: @Vanguard3000 much appreciated! Yeah I couldn't find much either but thanks for helping me puzzle this old memory together and encouraging me to watch it again because I remember it being unique as well!

Comment: @Clockwork it's blocking in my country as well unfortunately :/ thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bastron Try with [this proxy site](https://www.genmirror.com/). First, choose Youtube in the quick links below. Then paste the link of one of the Youtube videos into the search bar, and there you go.

Comment: @Clockwork no way, it actually WORKED!!! Woohooo thanks!!!

Comment: Nice! Thanks, @Clockwork! I've used this to get some screenshots to illustrate the answer. @Bastron I hope you enjoy the show. It's one of those shows that had a lot of potential, but bit off a bit more than it (or audiences) could chew.

Comment: What a strange film, certainly unique and I'm sure it could've reached its full potential if only it was given more time in  terms of additional episodes to flesh out the mysteries of the planet Rusta, which seemed to (at least from my impression) have its own life. The outdoor vistas were beautiful, especially the wide shots of the wall connecting to the dark side of the planet with vicious thunderstorms in the sky. No wonder such an odd film experience stood out as a childhood memory.